# Algorithmic analysis - do I have the right idea?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Is my take on what Big oh represents, correct?

T(n) represents a function/algorithm and n represents the size of an array for instance.

So if the function is for example  = 2n + 10 + 4n^3, the worst case here is that the function would have to loop over n n^3 times correct? thus the answer is T(n) <= O(n^3) correct? My main concern is how we get the function on the other side of f(n), the O(fn) part..I have seen some lectures on-line and they use a random function without even saying why they chose that. So we get the fn part in O(f(N)) by simply looking at the right function and seeing which step goes through n times the most in function T(n), in the worst case?In this example it being n^3.  Can we also say T(n) <= O(n^4) or T(n) <= O(n^5)? but have O(n^3) be the best worst case scenario, the most approximate estimation?

I'm trying to understand this and have spent a couple of days, I'm still trying to explain it to my self.

Omega finds the best case lower bound, what ever lower bound means.

I'm looking at all of this without the fancy maths that goes into it just to prove it.

Comment: Your idea isn't `rite`, but it isn't `rong` either.

Comment: You seem to replace every noun with `n`. So you say "`n` represents the size of `n`", or "`n` would have to loop over `n` `n^3` times". None of it makes any sense.

Comment: Oooops I will edit, I mean to say that the function will loop over n n^3 times at its worst case.

Comment: You're confused. The functions in explanations of big-O are usually expressions for some concrete number of operations in terms of data size. Examples are comparisons in a sort or instructions executed by some machine model. Bad explanations throw the world "time" around without explaining what that means. If (and there are many other possibilities), the function is a polynomial in n, T(n), then it's easy to show that as n gets larger, the polynomial term with highest degree dominates the value of T(n); the rest are there, but insignificant. Big-O is carefully defined to express this idea.

Answer (score 2):

> So if the function is for xample = 2n + 10 + 4n^3, the worst case here is that the function would have to loop over n n^3 times correct?

If T(n) *calculates* the value of 2n + 10 + 4n^3, that's O(1) as each of those maths operations is constant time.

If T(n) = 2n + 10 + 4n^3 describes the performance curve using a count of how many times the slowest operation will be performed, and that's described *exactly* by 2n + 10 + 4n^3, then it describes every case and not just the worst case.  But, it is possible that 2n + 10 + 4n^3 describes the worst case count of that operation.  We can't tell you - whomever describes the performance as 2n + 10 + 4n^3 must say what they're describing.

Either way, it's weird to say "loop over n n^3 times" as there's not necessarily any "n" to "loop" over - you have a count of the times some operation is performed, and even if that operation was done once per element in a loop (the closest thing to "loop over n"), then that looping would happen 2 + 4n^2 times - with 10 other operations also needed - as your "loop over n" removes a factor of "n" from your formula.

Still, I expect I'm just confusing you more, so let's look at an example:

```
n = #elements       2n + 10 + 4n^3 #operations
0                   0 + 10 + 0 = 10
1                   2 + 10 + 4 = 16
2                   4 + 10 + 4*8 = 46
...                 ...
```

> thus the answer is T(n) <= O(n^3) correct?

The big-O performance of T(n) above is O(n^3), and you could reasonably say that's <= itself, and < O(n^4) which are both less than O(n^5) etc..

> My main concern is how we get the function on the other side of f(n), the O(fn) part..I have seen some lectures online and they use a random function without even saying why they chose that. So we get the fn part in O(f(N)) by simply looking at the right function and seeing which step goes through n times the most in function T(n), in the worst case?

Yes, that's about right, though as I said you might but aren't necessarily "go[ing] through n", but you are doing some work a number of times related to n.

> In this example it being n^3. Can we also say T(n) <= O(n^4) or T(n) <= O(n^5)? but have O(n^3) be the best worst case senerio, the most approximate extimation?

This seems confused.  The T(n) above is O(n^3).  You can observe that that's *better*, < or <= O(n^4) - and in turn n^5 - but that observation doesn't change the efficiency.  Something that's O(n^3) is not also O(n^4).  It's a bit like saying the length of a ruler is 30cm, which is less than 40cm, but it would be wrong to say 30cm was the best length of the ruler - it's the only length of the ruler.  Still, in some cases, you might say one algorithm for solving a problem has the best worst-case efficiency (it can never get too slow regardless of the specific values it works upon), while another has the best typical-case efficiency (it's normally faster).

Answer (score 1):

`n` can be whatever you want but choose wisely; the runtime `T(n)` for sorting an array with `n = number of rabbits on Mars` makes no sense. So to make a sound argument you first need to find the variable(s) that actually have an effect on the runtime.

`T(n)` is an exact function. Sorting an array might take exactly `T(n) = 2 * C_1 * T(n/2) + C_2` where:

- `n = number of elements in array`
- `C_1 = some constant amount of time`
- `C_2 = some other constant amount of time`

But the exact runtime is often hard to pinpoint (it might be hard to calculate the exact value of `C_1` and `C_2`), and does in fact give us too much information. You can certainly care about the exact runtime but most of the time we only want to compare algorithms to each other. We want to know how they behave for large `n`s because that is when the complexity is going to make a difference; sorting an array of 100 elements is a problem you can solve in almost any naive way possible, even bubble sort, so that problem is not interesting or important.

This is where Big-O comes in. We try to find a formula which express the runtime in a way that we can compare different algorithms, get an idea about how they behave but at the same time don't care about the exact constants.

Big-O achieves these goals by **dropping all lower-order terms and constants**. The lower-order terms are those that will play a very small part of the runtime with large `n`s. For `T(n) = 2*n + n^3` and `n > 1 million` you see that the `2*n > 2 million` term is *dominated* by (much smaller than) the `n^3 > 10^18` term. We call the measure that Big-O gives us the *asymptotic runtime complexity* because as `n` grows larger the original exact function `T(n)` approaches `O(n)`. There is often talk about "large numbers" when explaining these things, but the definitions actually talk about when `n` approaches infinity. So my choice of "> 1 million" is just to help you visualize it in non-infinite terms.

Keep in mind that the entire exercise is an analysis tool and not an exact answer to what algorithm you should choose in any given situation. Often times you won't have larger `n`s, especially not infinitely large ones, and other times the constant factors that you dropped might be so large that one algorithm with worse runtime complexity is actually better for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be as short as possible.. Big Oh represents complexity of your program, algorithm, etc. As bigger Oh, the more time your algorithm will take, when we exclude machine specifics. Small n represents size of your problem(this depends on specific problem, sometimes it's size of some array, sometimes it's number of digits in variable, sometimes it`s value of variable itself, etc..).

Now, why we can  2n + 10 + 4n^3  write as O(n^3) .. It`s that if u take, n>N(this mean really big n, lets say 1mil, but you should imagine even bigger), those constants like 10, and 4 times, and even 2n(which is 2mil) don't seem to "scratch" that big guy n^3(1mil^3). Since, n^3 is so big, comparing to others in equation, we can then say that 2n + 10 + 4n^3 has complexity of O(n^3).